# Use FFmpeg to resize image

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg

Is it possible to resize an image using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)?

I have this so far:

```
ffmpeg. -i 1.jpg -vf scale=360:240 > 2.jpg
```

I get the error message:

> At least one output file must be specified

Is it possible?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf scale=320:240 output_320x240.png
```

I got this from [source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20(resizing)%20with%20ffmpeg)

**Note:** The scale filter can also automatically calculate a dimension while preserving the aspect ratio: `scale=320:-1`, or `scale=-1:240`

Comment: Hi, beat you to it. It was what I just found. But, as you got the right answer and you gave me your time I give you a tick :)

Comment: The scale filter can also automatically calculate a dimension while preserving the aspect ratio: `scale=320:-1`, or `scale=-1:240`.

Comment: This results in a corrupt image for me.  Just a bunch of lines and colors.  jpg to jpg

Comment: Interesting, png output works fine though.  JPG is borked.

Comment: What if I want to keep the output file name unchanged? Can I have a shorter command? Thank you.

Comment: I have created a 65,535x155-pixel waveform transparent png from an audio file with another ffmpeg command. And as I want some other resolutions such as 20,000x155, 10,000x155, and 1920x155, I tried using this code because I did not want to create another resolutions with the first time command to save time. It works but as my png has the transparent areas, I see grayed pixels around the waveform. Is there any solution to resize a transparent png image with ffmpeg maintaining the areas which are partly transparent?

Comment: The same command works for videos, by the way, if someone - like me - was wondering...

Answer (score 36):

If you want to retain aspect ratio you can do -

```
ffmpeg -i 1.jpg -vf scale="360:-1" 2.jpg
```

or if you want to resize based on input width and height, let's say half of input width and height you can do -

```
ffmpeg -i 1.jpg -vf scale="iw/1:ih/2" 2.jpg
```

where

```
iw: input width
ih: input height
```

Comment: I found this very useful.  It should be noted that the correct usage for cutting both height and width in half is -vf scale="iw/2:ih/2".

Answer (score 11):

It is also possible to resize an image to fit inside some dimensions and *letterbox* the rest.

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i IN.png -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" OUT.jpg
```

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/978289) for more details.

Comment: After a long online search and not knowing that this was called "letterboxing", this answer just saved me from a lot of hassle! Thanks so much!

Comment: Thank you, also the only answer I found online that correctly aspect fits multiple images

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to @andri-kurnia 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28806881/4650581).

This example also shows how to resize multiple images (in windows):

```
for %j in (*.jpg) do ffmpeg -i "%j" -vf scale=480:-1 "Small-%~nj.jpg"
```

This command will resize all `.jpg` images in the folder, sets the width 480 while keeping ratio, and add "Small-" at the start of the resized image name.
And I think for some types, it may be necessary to use -2 instead of -1. For specifying the height, we can use something like -1:480.

Answer (score 5):

To reduce image scale to the bounding box of width:320px and height:240px.

`ffmpeg -i src_image_path -vf 'scale=if(gte(a\,320/240)\,min(320\,iw)\,-2):if(gte(a\,320/240)\,-2\,min(240\,ih))' dst_image_path`

```
a: aspect ratio
iw: in width
ih: in height
```

If the src image size is in the bounding box do no resize on it.
If image has a big aspect ration than 320/240 and width is bigger then 320, resize width to 320 and keep the aspect ration. 
If image has a small aspect ration than 320/240 and height is bigger then 240, resize height to 240 and keep the aspect ration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did processing all the images in a directory:

```
for i in *.jpg; do ffmpeg -i $i -vf scale="iw/2:ih/2" ${i}; done
```

Its kind of a combination from all of the above, in my case image batch processing occurs quite frequently, so you can run above code in your image directory which will lower all jpg file resolution to a half "iw/2:ih/2", which in my case will be efficient enough.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?