# Java - How to pad and resize image without cropping?

Tags: java, image, resize

I need to resize alot of images from the ratio aspect (2:3) to (3:4).

The images are 800px x 1200px currently. I need them to be 600px x 800px eventually without any cropping.

May I know what libraries are available for me to do padding and resizing without cropping in Java?

Comment: See `Image.getScaledInstance(...)`

Comment: *"May I know what libraries are available for me to do padding and resizing without cropping in Java?"* I have voted to close this, but the short answer is AWT (classes in the `java.awt` & `java.awt.image` packages).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i have tried your method. When resizing to a smaller image, the image is squeeze such that the person in the image becomes thinner. When resizing to a bigger image, the image is stretch such that the person in the image becomes fatter.

Answer (score 4):

From your current Image (assuming a `java.awt.Image`) you can use :

- [`Image.getScaledInstance(w,h,h)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,int,int)) as method
- [`Image.SCALE_SMOOTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#SCALE_SMOOTH) as algorithm for resize

And these steps:

- compute the ratios in `width` and in `height`
- depending on their values (padding width or padding height)

  - compute the `width` and `height` to obtain the scaled image
  - compute the padding required
- write the image at the good position

```
static BufferedImage pad(BufferedImage image, double width, double height, Color pad) {
    double ratioW = image.getWidth() / width;
    double ratioH = image.getHeight() / height;
    double newWidth = width, newHeight = height;
    int fitW = 0, fitH = 0;
    BufferedImage resultImage;
    Image resize;

    //padding width
    if (ratioW < ratioH) {
        newWidth = image.getWidth() / ratioH;
        newHeight = image.getHeight() / ratioH;
        fitW = (int) ((width - newWidth) / 2.0);

    }//padding height
    else if (ratioH < ratioW) {
        newWidth = image.getWidth() / ratioW;
        newHeight = image.getHeight() / ratioW;
        fitH = (int) ((height - newHeight) / 2.0);
    }

    resize = image.getScaledInstance((int) newWidth, (int) newHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    resultImage = new BufferedImage((int) width, (int) height, image.getType());
    Graphics g = resultImage.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(pad);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height);
    g.drawImage(resize, fitW, fitH, null);
    g.dispose();

    return resultImage;
}
```

To use as

```
BufferedImage image = ...;
BufferedImage result = pad(image, 600, 800, Color.white);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i have tried your method. When resizing to a smaller image, the image is squeeze such that the person in the image becomes thinner. When resizing to a bigger image, the image is stretch such that the person in the image becomes fatter.

Comment: @SomeoneInNeedOfHelp try my code with a scale factor, because you may use dimensions that are not proportionnal, If you don"t preserve proportionnality it won't look the same that's normal

Comment: I need to resize alot of images from the ratio aspect (2:3) to (3:4). Your code for is resizing the image and keeping ratio aspect. I need to pad the image to change the ratio aspect.

Comment: @SomeoneInNeedOfHelp Found out. Edit with a method that works for both kind of padding, respect proportion and required size ;)

Comment: This solution is not working. It only returns white surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it using below code:
'w' is the amount of padding you need on each side.

```
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth()+2*w, image.getHeight(), 
image.getType());

Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();

g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillRect(0,0,image.getWidth()+2*w,image.getHeight());
g.drawImage(image, w, 0, null);
g.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ffmpeg can help you to do anything with image.
e.g. [Use ffmpeg to resize image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806816/use-ffmpeg-to-resize-image)

1. You can keep ffmpeg binaries in some conf folder.
2. Create sh script for ffmpeg command.
3. Use CommandLine from (Apache Commons exec library) to run the script.