# Is there a way to process images and videos in the website frontend?

Tags: javascript, image, video, frontend, compression

I am developing an application in Next.js and I need to be able to send images and videos to an API. These images and videos need to be compressed and they have to be in a specific format. I need to be able to process these medias in the frontend but I don't know if that is possible. I would like to know if there is a sharp package equivalent in the frontend and the same for videos. I thought about using WebAssembly but I don't know if that is the way to go.

I saw the solution that uses canvas but I don't like this option and that doesn't let me process videos.

Answer (score 0):

The most versatile video processing approach for front end, i.e. browser, is likely a ffmpeg based JavaScript implementation.

One of the leading implementations, which leverages Web Assemnply language is:

- https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm

You do need to be aware of the need for SharedArrayBuffer support:

> Only browsers with SharedArrayBuffer support can use ffmpeg.wasm, you
> can check HERE for the complete list. The link referred to above is
> here:

https://caniuse.com/sharedarraybuffer

Comment: And what about image processing?

Comment: @MartíSerraMolina - it depends on what you need to do but yes ffmpeg can process images - see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28806816/334402